# Chainlink VRF very slow - 20+ minutes for response to fulfillRandomness on Rinkeby

Tags: chainlink

I have implemented a basic Chainlink VRF function in Solidity and deployed to Ethereum test network Rinkeby

```
  function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId)
  {
    require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK");
    return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
  }

  function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override 
  {
    randomResult = randomness;
    _requestId = requestId;
  }
```

This works fine, deducts the LINK fee from my wallet, and eeeeeventually does call back `fulfillRandomness` with a random hex value, however it takes forever!

Just did a test and it took 30 minutes. Could I be doing something wrong or why is it taking so long? I know it's async and there's lots of stuff going on to fetch the random number, but at these speeds it's basically unusable right

Answer (score 1):

The Rinkeby testenet has had some downtime issues this weekend. You can use the Kovan testnet and VRF until Rinkeby is operating normally again.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Kovan and I'm reliably getting ~1 min VRF responses